# A bound of the harmonic series of squares.

Tags: probability, summation, boundary-value-problem, harmonic-numbers

I’ve been computing for some values of the sum and it seems that:

$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{n}
$$

But I’m not sure how to prove it… I tried induction but it doesn’t work… is there any other way?

This has to do in specific with the solution of Durrett’s book of probability: exercise 2.2.4

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without using integral, there's the classical trick:

$$\frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{k(k - 1)} = \frac{1}{k - 1} - \frac{1}{k}.$$

Summing up gives what you want.

Comment: Awesome! thank you.